# Using Goodreads API for android

Tags: android

I am building an android app which requires user reviews about a book. After searching in google, I found out that [Goodreads API](http://www.goodreads.com/api) can be good for this purpose.But the problem is that is there is no clear documentation for java or android.

How can I use **Goodreads API** for my app? Any code example can be good for explanation.

Comment: [First hit](https://github.com/rharter/goodreads-api) when searching for "goodreads java api".

Comment: @Michael how can i use this in my app?

Comment: https://www.goodreads.com/api first link that comes out when you google "goodreads java api", and its quiet clear in itself.

Answer (score 4):

Hello Guys,

```
               take the referral code form
```

[MarcBernstein/android-goodreads-api] 
https://github.com/MarcBernstein/android-goodreads-api

After this do the following changes in code if it is not compaitable with your            android studio.

In build.gradle-

```
    buildscript 
     {
    repositories {
    mavenCentral()
            }

    dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'
    classpath 'com.jakewharton.sdkmanager:gradle-plugin:0.9.+'
    }
  }

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
 compileSdkVersion 19
 buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 19
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}

packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/maven/commons-io/commons-io/pom.xml'
    exclude 'META-INF/maven/commons-io/commons-io/pom.properties'
}

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}

packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
}



buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), '        proguard-rules.txt'
    }
  }
}

 dependencies {
   compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
   compile project(':libraries:android-goodreads-api')
   compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.+'
   compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.4'
   compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.5.0'
   compile ('com.squareup.retrofit:converter-simplexml:1.5.0') {
    exclude module: 'stax'
    exclude module: 'stax-api'
    exclude module: 'xpp3'
  }
 compile 'org.json:json:20140107'
 compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-io:+'
 compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:+'
 compile 'com.google.guava:guava:16.+'
 compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:+'
 compile 'oauth.signpost:signpost-core:+'
 compile 'oauth.signpost:signpost-commonshttp4:+'
 compile ('org.simpleframework:simple-xml:+') {
    exclude module: 'stax'
    exclude module: 'stax-api'
    exclude module: 'xpp3'
  }
 }
```

After this change in goodsreads Api Gradle file---

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
  compileSdkVersion 19
  buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'

 defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 19
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
 }

 compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
 }
 buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),     'proguard-rules.txt'
     }
  }
 }

dependencies {
  compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
  compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.+'
  compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.4'
  compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.5.0'
  compile ('com.squareup.retrofit:converter-simplexml:1.5.0') {
    exclude module: 'stax'
    exclude module: 'stax-api'
    exclude module: 'xpp3'
  }
  compile 'org.json:json:20140107'
  compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-io:+'
  compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:+'
  compile 'com.google.guava:guava:16.+'
  compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:+'
  compile 'oauth.signpost:signpost-core:+'
  compile 'oauth.signpost:signpost-commonshttp4:+'
  compile ('org.simpleframework:simple-xml:+') {
    exclude module: 'stax'
    exclude module: 'stax-api'
    exclude module: 'xpp3'
   }
 }
```

**3.  change your class path of Gradle file.**

**4. configuration data**

```
<string name="oauth_developer_key">your developer key</string>
<string name="oauth_developer_secret">your developer secret</string>
<string name="oauth_callback_url">com.goodreads://oauth_callback</string>
```

**5. change in GoodreadsAPI File of libraries Module**

private static final String API_URL = "https://www.goodreads.com/";

```
private static final String AUTHORIZATION_WEBSITE_URL = "http://www.goodreads.com/oauth/authorize?mobile=1";
private static final String ACCESS_TOKEN_ENDPOINT_URL = "http://www.goodreads.com/oauth/access_token";
private static final String REQUEST_TOKEN_ENDPOINT_URL = "http://www.goodreads.com/oauth/request_token";
```

Answer (score 1):

Goodreads api is one of the worst I've ever seen.

You can use [grapi library](https://github.com/intmainreturn00/grapi) to make working with it simpler.
Spoiler - I'm the author. It is written in modern kotlin. 
You can use it like this:

```
launch {
    val userId = grapi.getUserId()
    val shelves = grapi.getUserShelves(1, userId.id)
    val reviews = grapi.getReviewList(
            userId.id,
            "read",
            1, 2,
            sort = Sort.NUM_PAGES,
            order = Order.DESCENDING
    )
    val book = grapi.getBookByISBN("837054150X")
    val book2 = grapi.getBookByGRID("13588846")
    val res = grapi.getSearchResults("Wiedźmin")
    val user = grapi.getUser(userId.id)
    val allReviews = grapi.getAllReviews(userId.id)
}
```

Feel free to open an issue if any question or PR.